# Using C++20 ranges with istreambuf_iterator

Tags: c++, c++20

I can't compile a (very contrived) [C++ ranges example](https://godbolt.org/z/fFp95w):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

template <typename R>
auto populate(R&& range)
{
    return std::vector<char>(range.begin(), range.end());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto stream = std::ifstream{"/etc/hosts"};

    const auto is_odd = [](auto i) { return (i % 2) == 1; };
    const auto hosts_data = populate(
        std::ranges::subrange{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{stream},
                              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}} |
        std::views::filter(is_odd)
    );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Results in:

```
<source>:19:35:   required from here
<source>:9:17: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<char>::vector(std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::subrange<std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ranges::subrange_kind::unsized>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:13)> >::_Iterator, std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::subrange<std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ranges::subrange_kind::unsized>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(auto:13)> >::_Iterator)'

    9 |     return std::vector<char>(range.begin(), range.end());
      |
```

From further experimentation, it appears that the use of `istreambuf_iterator` is causing the problem, but I don't know why.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This makes me sad.

---

`filter_view::iterator` is specified as, from [[range.filter.iterator]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter.iterator):

```
constexpr iterator& operator++();
constexpr void operator++(int);
constexpr iterator operator++(int) requires forward_range<V>;
```

Notably, a `subrange` of `istreambuf_iterator<char>` is not a `forward_range` - it is an `input_range` (because `istreambuf_iterator` is only an `input_iterator`).

Thus, the *postfix* `operator++` returns `void` instead of `iterator`.

As a result of that, our particular `filter_view::iterator` does *not* meet the requirements of *`cpp17-iterator`* as specified in [[iterator.traits]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.traits#2):

```
template<class I>
concept cpp17-iterator =
  copyable<I> && requires(I i) {
    {   *i } -> can-reference;
    {  ++i } -> same_as<I&>;
    { *i++ } -> can-reference; // we fail this one
  };
```

The constructor you're trying to call in `vector` is specified as, from [[vector.overview]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.overview):

```
template<class InputIterator>
  constexpr vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Which means, from [[sequence.reqmts]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#13):

> If the constructor
>
> ```
> template<class InputIterator>
>   X(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>     const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
> ```
>
> is called with a type `InputIterator` that does not qualify as an input iterator, then the constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.

And our iterator type does *not* qualify as an input iterator because the result of postfix increment isn't dereferencable (see also [this table](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#tab:inputiterator)).

---

At least this is just an input iterator, so it's not like there's any gain in efficiency to be had anyway, so you can just change your implementation of `populate()` to `if constexpr` based on whether you actually get a cpp17-iterator out of it (based on checking `is_constructible`) and just loop/`push_back` otherwise.

For some reason `ranges::to` from range-v3 doesn't compile here but I think that one's a compiler issue.

Comment: You're right, there's no gain in efficiency, I just wanted some C++20 _snazziness_.  Oh well, I guess I'll go back to ye olde `for` loops (that are much easier to read...).

Comment: @cmannett85 I mean, I still wish this worked. That's why I'm sad.